# Can I travel to Germany from a country different from the one I got the visa from?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas

I am currently in the process of applying for a Schengen Visa to Germany for the month of August. I live in Egypt while my parents live in Saudi Arabia. I finish my Exams at the end of June and was hoping to stay in Saudi Arabia for the month of July and then travel to Germany from there. Is it possible to travel from Saudi Arabia to Germany if I got my visa from Egypt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Germany will not care where you started your trip from. As long as you abide by the rules of your visa you will be able to arrive from any country you like.

Answer (score -4):

Under the Schengen rules, you must enter the Schengen area via the country for which the visa was issued, moreover, the majority of your time in the Schengen area should be spent in that country, although you are free, (normally) to travel to any country within the Schengen free travel area.

Comment: There is no requirement to enter through the country issuing the visa.  In fact, if such a requirement were implemented alongside the "main destination" rule, it would be impossible for someone in (for example) Serbia who requires a Schengen visa to get one to drive to Germany, or for a flight via Vienna to Paris.